# Extending template class with a class and with a template

Tags: c++, gcc

I was trying to make a shortcut class for malloc'd unique_ptr, but I failed to extend it with default constructor. That's why I tried to make the same action on my example class, to get my hands on the error. This works perfectly:

```
namespace paw {
    template<class T, class F>
    class Cl {
    public:
        Cl(T* t, F f): t(t), f(f) {}
        virtual ~Cl() { if (t!= 0) { f(t); } }
    private:
        T* t;
        F f;
    };
}

class ClInt : public paw::Cl<int, std::function<void(int*)>> {
public:
    ClInt() : Cl(0, free) {}
    ClInt(int* t) : Cl(t, free) {}
};

int main() {
    ClInt clint;
}
```

However when I generalize ClInt class:

```
namespace paw {
    template<class T, class F>
    class Cl {
    public:
        Cl(T* t, F f): t(t), f(f) {}
        virtual ~Cl() { if (t!= 0) { f(t); }}
    private:
        T* t;
        F f;
    };

}

template<class T>
class ClInt : public paw::Cl<T, std::function<void(T*)>> {
public:
    ClInt() : Cl(0, free) {}
    ClInt(T* t) : Cl(t, free) {}


};

int main() {
    ClInt<int> clint;
}
```

i get this strange error:

```
error: class 'ClInt<T>' does not have any field named 'Cl'
```

However I cannot call superclass constructor with `paw::` namespace because I get

```
error: expected class-name before '(' token
```

What is the difference and why this is not working?

Comment: when I do `ClInt() : paw::Cl(0, free) {}` I get `error: expected class-name before '(' token`

Comment: missing typename somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the full signature for the template instances like this:

```
template<class T>
class ClInt : public paw::Cl<T, std::function<void(T*)>> {
public:
    ClInt() : paw::Cl<T, std::function<void(T*)>>(0, free) {}
    ClInt(T* t) : paw::Cl<T, std::function<void(T*)>>(t, free) {}


};
```